# Self Hosted Agent service startup getting failed on VM restart

Tags: azure-devops, service, systemd, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have installed a self hosted agent in my company's private cloud VM (followed [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops-2022) and it got successfully installed as service and running.

Now I tried to test it as system startup, so rebooted my machine. After reboot when I am checking the status of service using `sudo ./svc.sh status` seeing below error

```
/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.Organization.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgent\x2dPool.pc1231bg1111.service
● vsts.agent.Organization.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgent\x2dPool.pc1231bg1111.service - Azure Pipelines Agent (Organization.Ppe-Item-Price-Agent-Pool.pc1231bg1111)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.Organization.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgent\x2dPool.pc1231bg1111.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-03-29 06:51:24 GMT; 7min ago
  Process: 1047 ExecStart=/home/OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce/myagent/runsvc.sh (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 1047 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Mar 29 06:51:24 pc1231bg1111.tgrc.myorg.org systemd[1]: Started Azure Pipelines Agent (Organization.Ppe-Item…1053).
Mar 29 06:51:24 pc1231bg1111.tgrc.myorg.org systemd[1]: vsts.agent.Organization.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgen…7/USER
Mar 29 06:51:24 pc1231bg1111.tgrc.myorg.org systemd[1]: vsts.agent.Organization.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgen…code'.
```

My agent directory

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users  2014 Feb 22 08:27 run.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users  2753 Feb 22 08:27 run-docker.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users  9465 Feb 22 08:27 license.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users   726 Feb 22 08:27 env.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users  3173 Feb 22 08:27 config.sh
drwxr-xr-x  7 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users    82 Feb 22 08:28 externals
-rwxr-xr-x  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users  4643 Mar  8 12:32 svc.sh
drwxr-xr-x  7 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users    80 Mar 12 12:24 _work
drwxr-xr-x 27 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users 16384 Mar 29 06:41 bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users   512 Mar 29 06:41 runsvc.sh
drwxr-xr-x  3 OrgDomain+svc-Itemsrvce OrgDomain+domain users    19 Mar 29 06:49 _diag
```

Service under `/etc/systemd/system/`

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  369 Mar 29 06:41 'vsts.agent.MyOrg.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgent\x2dPool.pc1231bg1111.service'
```

Could someone suggest how can I debug it further to find root cause ?

Thanks

Comment: The error 217 indicate the user did not exist at the time the service tried to start. The cause of the issue could be that the user used to run the agent service is not valid. Can you check the content of file: `vsts.agent.MyOrg.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgent\x2dPool.pc1231bg1111.service` and check the `[Service] block -> User`? You can check if the user exists or change to set other existing users.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I checked the content of service file and it's showing correct user. Not sure how this user doesn't exist and I have setup the agent with this user (sudo su - $username) only. Didn't get "Service] block -> User" part ?

Comment: Can you try to re-install the agent with the command: `sudo ./svc.sh install username` to set the user to run the service?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I believe by default sudo ./svc.sh install will also attach the current user  we are using to call sudo. Anyways let me specifically mention the username  and try

Comment: Feel free to share the result. And we need to use the local machine user instead of  part of some external user store (e.g. Active Directory).

Comment: Or you can try to use the `root` to run the agent service. `sudo ./svc.sh install root` Based on my test, the root user also can be used in the agent service.

Comment: It's still same on using "sudo ./svc.sh install username". What do you mean why local machine user. I got a service account created from support team and using that to login and running the agent service.

Comment: It's possible that service account aren't yet available at the time the system is started during boot. You can try to add/update the After field value to  `After=nss-user-lookup.target` in the **vsts.agent.MyOrg.Ppe\x2dItem\x2dPrice\x2dAgent\x2dPool.pc1231bg1111.service file -> [Unit] block**. For the local machine user, I mean that the actual user account on linux machine(e.g. root).